# Efficient solution to linear matrix equations

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, computational-geometry, numerical-linear-algebra

A general form for a linear matrix equation can be written as
$$AX + XB + \sum C_iXD_i$$

If $C_i$ and $D_i$ are all 0, then this simplifies into a well known and studied matrix equation that has an efficient solutions using various factorisations. I am wondering if there are efficient solutions to the more general case.

By more efficient solutions, I mean more efficient then simply vectorising X and converting the problem into  matrix-vector equation.

I suspect the answer is no, so if this is the case, I am wondering if there is a more efficient solution to the more specific equation
$$\sum XA_iA_i^T + B_i^TB_iX - B_iXA_i^T - B_i^TXA_i$$

Where $A_i$ and $B_i$ are positive semidefinite and possibly symmetric.

The reason I ask is that this matrix equation is currently a bottleneck in the code I am writing, and the shear amount of structure to this equation seems to beg for a more efficient solution.